# Make a PGFkeys path take precedence over another path for a whole scope

Tags: pgfkeys

I've been writing a package for LaTeX lately called [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman).  It is an extension to Ti*k*Z and just like PGFplots, it defines a new environment within `{tikzpicture}` called `{feynman}` and makes available new commands and styles within.

I have defined all my keys and styles related to Ti*k*Z-Feynman within a branch called `/tikzfeynman` in PGFkeys and ideally I would like to have it such that within the `{feynman}` environment, the `/tikzfeynman` path is always searched first before moving on.

The way I have been achieving this so far is basically to have:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /tikzfeynman/.cd,
  /tikzfeynman/.search also={/tikz},
  ...
}
```

But looking at it now, it seems like a suboptimal solution.  Firstly, it requires the whole `.cd` and `.search also` to be prefixed everywhere, and it seems to be incompatible with new `.style` that make use of keys within `/tikzfeynman` (see [this bug](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/9)).

The issue is further complicated by the fact that Ti*k*Z-Feynman uses the graph drawing library and thus in some occasions, it will have to search the `/tikz/graphs` and `/graph drawing` paths too (but not always).

I have been trying to look at how PGFplots handles this with its `{axis}`  environments, but so far I haven't been able to identify what I need (if PGFplots even does this).

So is there a way to make a PGFkeys path (or family) take precedence within a `\begingroup ... \endgroup` (or `\scope ... \endscope`)?  And (optionally), can this also apply inside a `graph`?

---

Here is a minimal (non-)working example that illustrates the issue I would like to fix.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%% Hidden to the user
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.is family,
  /foo/.search also={/tikz},
}
\def\fooset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}
\fooset{
  key a/.style={
    key b,
    key c,
  },
  key b/.style={
    /tikz/red,
  },
  key c/.style={
    /tikz/thick,
  },
}

\makeatletter
\def\fooenv{
  \begingroup
  % Neither of the following seem to do anything as the /.cd only applies to
  % keys within the same command call.
  \pgfkeys{/foo/.cd,/foo/.search also={/tikz}}
  \scope[/foo/.cd,/foo/.search also={/tikz}]
}
\def\endfooenv{
  \endscope
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

%% What a user might do
\fooset{
  my key/.style={
    key c,
    blue,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % The following should fail because we are not in fooenv.
  \draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
  \begin{fooenv}
    % The following should work since we are now in fooenv, but don't.
    \draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \draw [my key] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
    % In this case, it finds key a fine, but fails to find key c.
    \draw [/foo/my key] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \end{fooenv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can first `/.try` and then pass it to `\tikzset`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, what you're suggesting is equivalent to what I'm current doing.  By setting `/.search also` and `/.cd`ing into the right path, PGFkeys first attempts to find the key in `/tikzfeynman` and if that fails, tries in the paths given in the `/.search also`.

Also, this doesn't really set `/tikzfeynman` as the first search path within the whole scope which is the main issue I'm facing.

Please correct me if you meant something else.

Comment: If you `/.try` it only tries in the current context. Then if fails you can then push it to `\pgfkeysalso` and other places. `/.search also` basically expands the current key family to include others.

Comment: Are you saying that I should get users of Ti*k*Z-Feynman to write `/.try`?  I'm not quite sure how that would be implemented.  Also, what would happen if I wanted to override a `/tikz` key so that my key takes precedence?

I have updated the initial post with a minimal (non-)working example that illustrates the issue.

Comment: There is a fatal deficiency in your code: `\draw[key a]` passes `key a` to `\tikzset`, so `/tikz` is always the *a* choice, and in fact *the first* choice.

Comment: I'm well aware the `\draw[key a]` will search `/tikz` first; hence my question :)

Comment: @JP-Ellis OK... then... do you want to redefine `\tikzset` inside your environment?

Comment: Actually, I just posted an answer of a half-working attempt I had originally tried which involves modifying `/tikz/.unknown`.  I haven't attempted to modify `\tikzset` because I'm not sure that keys are directly handled by `\tikzset` when passed to `\node`, `\draw`, etc.  Indeed, having `\def\tikzset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}` in the definition of `\fooenv` doesn't seem to help :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## An non-pgfkeys approach

Let `\tikzset` be `\foobar` inside your environment. This might be the easiest way. (In the manner that I added just one line.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}

%% Hidden to the user
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.is family,
  /foo/.search also={/tikz},
}
\def\fooset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}
\fooset{
  key a/.style={
    key b,
    key c,
  },
  key b/.style={
    red,
  },
  key c/.style={
    thick,
  },
}
\def\fooenv{
    \begingroup
    \let\tikzset\fooset
}
\def\endfooenv{
    \endgroup
}

%% What a user might do
\fooset{
  my key/.style={
    key c,
    blue,
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{fooenv}
    \draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \draw [my key] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
    \draw [/foo/my key] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \end{fooenv}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## A pgfkeys handler approach

In TeX's language, what you try to do is much like

```
\let\oldtikzpath=\tikzpath
\def\tikzpath={\foopath \oldtikzpath}
```

This function is provide by TeX at the lowest level. Pgfkeys does not have this function yet. But we can create it by something like

```
\pgfkeys{
    /handlers/.cd redirect/.code={
        % store the redirection target somewhere
    },
    /handlers/.new cd/.code={
        % check if user set new target manually
         % cd properly
    }
}
```

A small example goes

```
\pgfkeys{
    /handlers/.cd redirect/.code={
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/cd target}{#1}
    },
    /handlers/.new cd/.code={
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/cd target}\pgfkeysredirectpath
        \ifx\pgfkeysredirectpath\relax
            \edef\pgfkeysdefaultpath{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/}
        \else
            \edef\pgfkeysdefaultpath{\pgfkeysredirectpath/}
        \fi
    }
}

\pgfkeys{
    /bar/.cd redirect={/foo},
}

\pgfkeys{
    /foo/foo/.code={foo-foo},
    /bar/bar/.code={bar-bar}
}

\pgfkeys{
    /bar/.cd,
    bar
}

\pgfkeys{
    /bar/.new cd,
    foo
}
```

We can even redefine `.cd` by how we define `.new cd`.

---

Just one step away: `\xxxxset`-family are define by `\pgfqkeys`. The manual say that it is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{#1/.cd,#2}`. In reality, `\pgfqkeys` defines `\pgfkeysdefaultpath` without calling handler `.cd`. So we have to redefine `\pgfqkeys`, either by calling `.new cd` or copy-and-pasting the if-statement again.

---

A sidenote: the manual claims

> The setting of a key is always local to the current TEX group.

So it is OK to say `/tikz/.cd redirect=to somewhere` or something similar in your own environment. The effect "expires" once you leave the environment.

## Old Answer

The design of pgfkeys makes no easy way to "cut the line". By "line" I mean that if you say

```
\pgfkeys{
    /a/.search also={
        /b,
        /c
    }
}
```

then pgfkeys will try to search `/a/x`, `/b/x`, `/c/x` in this order if one issues `/a/.cd,x=something`. That is,  `/a`, `/b`, `/c` are "lined up" and you cannot reorder it.

In your example, `\draw[key a]` is ultimately passed to `\tikzset{key a}`. Therefore

- pgfkeys will search under `/tikz`;
- pgfkeys will **NOT** search `/foo` unless you says `/tikz/.search also={/foo}`.
- Even if you said so, `/tikz` is still the first candidate.
- And the worst thing is: it destroys colors specification and arrows specification.

To come over this, you have to add alias under `/tikz` manually. There are already plenty of aliases: `every picture`, `every axis`, `every graph`, etc.

Otherwise you have to ask package users to put options at proper place. Just like

```
\tikz\path(0,0)[rotate=30]node{rotated?};
```

and

```
\tikz\path(0,0)node[rotate=30]{rotated?};
```

---

Nonetheless, here there is still good news: For options passed to `\fooset`, pgfkeys will try `/foo/x` and `/tikz/x` in this order provided that you said `\fooset{.search also={/tikz}}` somewhere before.

Hence you might want to create special commands such as `\foodraw` to replace `\draw`. Then you are certain that `\foodraw[key a]` does pass `key a` to `\fooset`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What you suggest is mostly what I have been doing already.  Trying to define alternatives to the standard TikZ commands and also make use of the `every <element>/.style` keys; however, this only gets me so far.  I was hoping there be a better way.

Comment: I can't find time to write an example but `\tikzset` is nothing but a pgfkeys shortcut. You can hack it at the start of the environment and pass everything to a `/foo/key/.try` first and, depending on the success or not, pass to TikZ. That allows an unknown key to avoid an error but instead set an if clause.

Comment: @percusse at the beginning OP is not sure if all options are passed through `\tikzset`. For me the point is different: I recognize pgfkeys as an alternative to primitive TeX commands. So in any case I prefer pgfkeys (handler) approach.

Comment: Yes but It is a pgfkeys approach. /.try /.retry etc. are all valid key handlers. If you have time, you can install a filter as pgfplots does.

Comment: @percusse at the beginning OP is not sure if all options are passed through `\tikzset`. For me the point is different: I recognize pgfkeys as an alternative to TeX primitives. So in any case I prefer pgfkeys (handler) approach. In this particular case, we should not develop decorative commands unless we have appropriate handlers. And even the handler (`.new cd`) should be defined by handlers, such as `.if defined then else`.

Comment: @percusse I apologize that I did not take your suggestion too seriously. But since you mention pgfplots and filter, I would have a look of the source code. Just for the record, I want `\tikzset` to be an alias; meaningful contents such as if-clause should be put elsewhere, perhaps in a handler.

Comment: @Symbol1 No problem at all. I'll try to make an example if I can find some time

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work though I didn't test properly. What I did is fiddle with the foo/.unknown part and then copy the rest of the /tikz/.unknown part.

What happens is that once `/foo/<key>=<value>` fails we give up on the family of `foo` and change to TikZ. The detail needs to be handled (and that's the part I copied) is that colors, arrows and shapes are not styles! So `stealth-latex` actually goes and looks for a style for that named key and then falls back to the handler I've copied.

So they need to be taken care of properly (which is amazing to start with that this exists for my taste of user friendliness).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%% Hidden to the user
\pgfkeys{/foo/.is family}
\def\fooset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}
\makeatletter
\def\installfooset{
  \def\tikzset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}%
    \pgfkeys{/foo/.unknown/.code={%
      \let\foo@key\pgfkeyscurrentname%
      \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,/tikz/\foo@key/.try={##1}}%
        \ifpgfkeyssuccess\typeout{I've passed "\foo@key" to TikZ}\else%
        \let\tikz@key\foo@key%
        % Start copying and print on the terminal
        \typeout{TikZ also didn't like "\foo@key"! Maybe arrow,color, or shape?}
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter!\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
      % this is a color!
      \expandafter\tikz@addoption\expandafter{\expandafter\tikz@compat@color@set\expandafter{\tikz@key}}%
      \edef\tikz@textcolor{\tikz@key}%
    \else%
      \pgfutil@doifcolorelse{\tikz@key}
      {%     
        \expandafter\tikz@addoption\expandafter{\expandafter\tikz@compat@color@set\expandafter{\tikz@key}}%
        \edef\tikz@textcolor{\tikz@key}%
      }%
      {%
        % Ok, second chance: This might be an arrow specification:
        \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter-\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@%
          % Ah, an arrow spec!
          \expandafter\tikz@processarrows\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
        \else%
          % Ok, third chance: A shape!
          \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@s@\tikz@key\endcsname\relax%
            \pgfkeys{/errors/unknown key/.expand
            once=\expandafter{\expandafter/\expandafter t\expandafter
            i\expandafter k\expandafter z\expandafter/\tikz@key}{##1}}%
          \else%
            \edef\tikz@shape{\tikz@key}%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      }%
    \fi%
  \fi%
        }
    }
}
\def\fooenv{\begingroup\installfooset\scope[]}
\def\endfooenv{\endscope\endgroup}
\makeatother


\fooset{
  key a/.style={key b,key c,},
  key b/.style={/tikz/red!40},
  key c/.style={/tikz/thick},
}
%% What a user might do
\fooset{my key/.style={key c,blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Fails with unknown [key a] ... Done!
  %\draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    % Works... Done!
  \begin{fooenv}
    \draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \draw [my key] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
        % Does it overwrite? Done!
    \draw [/foo/my key,dashed,key b,blue] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \end{fooenv}
  % Uninstalled? ... Done!
  %\draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It will hopefully print out the following to the terminal

```
I've passed "draw" to TikZ
I've passed "line width" to TikZ
I've passed "draw" to TikZ
I've passed "line width" to TikZ
TikZ also didn't like "blue"! Maybe arrow,color, or shape?
I've passed "draw" to TikZ
I've passed "line width" to TikZ
TikZ also didn't like "blue"! Maybe arrow,color, or shape?
I've passed "dashed" to TikZ
TikZ also didn't like "blue"! Maybe arrow,color, or shape?
```

Notice how `red!40` doesn't appear because it travels the legitimate `/.unknown` code.

Having said that, what you are trying to do is against the TikZ design essentials. The idea is to get out of the way of the  user and leave entrance points to modify every detail as much as possible. Hence overwriting existing keys are pretty against this mantra. That's why you have lots and lots of `every .../.style=...` keys in TikZ.

If you overwrite a TikZ key you are shaving off some of the functionality that might be needed for a power user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!  I'll have a look at whether I can get it to fix [this issue](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/9).  Also I realize that overriding keys is against the general way TikZ works and I definitely do not intend to do it much at all; however, I don't think it is unreasonable to slightly modify certain keys only within the `{feynman}` environment.

Comment: Curiously, is there a reason (other than to integrate the `typeout` commands) for including the whole TikZ `.unknown/.code` instead of using `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/.unknown/.@cmd}{\orig@tikz@search}` like I have in my answer?

Comment: @JP-Ellis Not really it's a habit since I usually modify stuff. Here you can also push your other package dependent options etc. following the TikZ mantra with a custom key `execute at unknown key` for example. So that you can execute other non-TikZ but pgfkeyed stuff and so on. Also notice that this is now `foo/.unknown` you have `tikz/.unknown` as a difference

Answer (score 1):

One of the ideas of toying with is trying to override certain Ti*k*Z function within the scope of the environment.  In particular, trying to override `/tikz/.unknown/.@cmd` such that it first search `/foo` before doing what it would usually do.

This is not the best solution for me because this does not allow me to override keys in `/tikz` with keys in `/foo`, though admittedly this isn't a deal breaker since I wouldn't want to do that too much as it could lead to some confusion to people using the package.

This works for keys which are explicitly specified (such as `key a` and `my key`) but unfortunately it does not seem to work for keys referred to within the style.  The error message is `I do not know '/key b'`, so for some reason keys within styles are handled differently... but how?

Another peculiarity is the case of `/foo/my key`.  Since this is a full key, it does not need to be searched for, and instead `key c` passes through `/tikz/.unknown` and is successfully found.  What is then strange is that it fails to find `blue` and actually produces some errors (extra `\else`, and many incomplete `\if` and `\ifx`).

Here is a modified version of the MWE above which implements the modified `/tikz/.unknown`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%% Hidden to the user
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.is family,
  /foo/.search also={/tikz},
}
\def\fooset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}
\fooset{
  key a/.style={key b, key c},
  key b/.style={red},
  key c/.style={thick},
}

\def\fooenv{
  \scope
  \ammend@search@path
}
\def\endfooenv{
  \endscope
}

\def\ammend@search@path{%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/.unknown/.@cmd}{\orig@tikz@search}
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/.unknown/.code=%
    \let\unknown@key\pgfkeyscurrentname
    \pgfkeys{/foo/\unknown@key/.try={##1}}
    \ifpgfkeyssuccess\else
    \let\pgfkeyscurrentname\unknown@key
    \orig@tikz@search##1\pgfeov
  }
}
\makeatother

%% What a user might do
\fooset{
  my key/.style={key c, blue}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % The following should fail because we are not in fooenv.
  \draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
  \begin{fooenv}
    % The following should work since we are now in fooenv, but don't.
    \draw [key a] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \draw [my key] (0, 0) -- (0, 1);
    % In this case, it finds key a fine, but fails to find key c.
    \draw [/foo/my key] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \end{fooenv}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```