# Problem between pgfkeys, tikz and personal macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, pgfkeys

The following minimal working example shows the problem. The mainmacro is an example of what I need; here I want to use my keys and keys from tikz (like draw,color,shape). The result is fine only if I use `shape = circle`. `circle` is not enough. Idem if I want the color red. `color = red` is obligatory. What is wrong in my code ? Do you know a better way to achieve what I want ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/.cd,
d/.code                     = {\def\macro@d{#1}},   
a/.code                     = {\def\macro@a{#1}},
/mykeys/.unknown/.code      = {\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                                               \pgfkeysalso{\searchname/.try=#1,
                                                    /tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1}
                              }    
        }  
\def\mainmacro{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\main@macro}{\main@macro[]}}
\def\main@macro[#1](#2)#3{%
\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{mykeys/.cd,
           d = 1,
           a = 45}
  \pgfqkeys{/mykeys}{#1}
  \path (#2) --+(\macro@a:\macro@d) node[/mykeys/.cd,#1] {#3};
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --( 1,1) coordinate (a) ;
        \mainmacro[a=0,d=12pt,draw,shape=circle](a){label 1}    
        \mainmacro[d=2cm,draw,circle](a){label 2}       
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/mykeys/.cd,
d/.store in                 = {\macro@d},   
a/.store in                 = {\macro@a},
/mykeys/.unknown/.code      = {\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                                               \pgfkeysalso{\searchname/.try=#1,
                                                    /tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1,
                                                    /tikz/.cd,#1}}}  

\def\mainmacro{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\main@macro}{\main@macro[]}}
\def\main@macro[#1](#2){%
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{mykeys/.cd,
           d = 1,
           a = 1}
\pgfqkeys{/mykeys}{#1}

\draw[/mykeys/.cd,#1] (\macro@a,\macro@a) circle (\macro@d) --++(1,1) node[#1] {label};% 
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) ;
        \mainmacro[red,ultra thick](a)       
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick works for the node but not with `\draw` perhaps I'm wrong somewhere in my code

Comment: I think `/.store in` handler is better here.

Comment: @percusse why do you think it's better ? there is a document about this ? I have some difficulties with the pgfmanual about this ... a complete example would be better

Comment: I guess it handles the current scope better but I don't have any rigorous argument. It might be just a pschological preference.

Comment: @percusse no psch. because with your code 1. I get an error if I use `.code` instead of `.store in` and I am not happy not understand why ! Perhaps it's a new question interesting ?

Comment: I think I know why the order matters. I'll check at home.

Comment: @percusse I change the code because it was an horrible mix

Comment: The true problem is your usage of `#1` in `\main@macro`: you use it to pass keys to your own code, to pass keys to a path (`\draw` or `\path`) and to pass keys to a node.  This mixture is the cause of all problems. It would be better to separate it all properly.

Comment: I agree with you. But I pass keys to the node only to make a test. The main idea is to draw something with options from tikz and with some characteristics (here a and d). Do you think it's possible to separate my own code and the options ( color etc) ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit mainmacro draws a circle it's natural to pass the radius and the style at the same time but it's interesting if you have another idea

Comment: @AlainMatthes You may define your new keys in `\mainmacro` with the `/tikz` key path.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Can you add this in your answer because I'm not sure to understand. If I have a lot of macros  at the end the mixture is in the `/tikz` key path, no ? For example is it possible in this case that a macro uses the keys of another macro ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because shape, color names (and some other stuff) are not keys. In other words, when you write `red` or `diamond` it doesn't have a dedicated key for such things. Hence, it goes through the TikZ machinery of `searchname/.retry` but because no such key is there it fails. Instead `/tikz/.unknown/.code` is much more comprehensive and sophisticated. For example

```
{%
        % Ok, second chance: This might be an arrow specification:
        \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter-\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@%
          % Ah, an arrow spec!
          \expandafter\tikz@processarrows\expandafter{\tikz@key}%
        \else%
          % Ok, third chance: A shape!
          \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@s@\tikz@key\endcsname\relax%
            \pgfkeys{/errors/unknown key/.expand
            once=\expandafter{\expandafter/\expandafter t\expandafter
            i\expandafter k\expandafter z\expandafter/\tikz@key}{##1}}%
          \else%
            \edef\tikz@shape{\tikz@key}%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      }%
```

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. You can in the end of the key trial, pass to TikZ explicitly and let it decide what to do. Hence you add the following

   ```
   \pgfkeys{/mykeys/.cd,
   d/.store in            = {\macro@d},   
   a/.store in            = {\macro@a},
   /mykeys/.unknown/.code = {\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname%
                             \pgfkeysalso{\searchname/.try=#1,
                             /tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1,
                             /tikz/.cd,#1}% <--- Now invoked under TikZ
                            }
   }
   ```

   Here, we explicitly trigger TikZ unknown machinery since the family is TikZ now. Hence goes through all the shape name checks and so on.
2. Write your own `/.unknown/.code` handler to account for known names. For example in [Make a PGFkeys path take precedence over another path for a whole scope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290490/) there are a few examples.

Comment: I need to study your answer but I agree with you for the diagnostic about the keys. The two ways proposed are interesting.

Comment: Your code works with a  `node` but with my new code `\draw ...`

Answer (score 4):

Here is two simple solutions.

### First solution (the better ?)

You may use the `/.search also` handler (see p.891 of pgfmanual, v3.0.1a):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/.cd,
  d/.code                     = {\def\macro@d{#1}},   
  a/.code                     = {\def\macro@a{#1}},
  /mykeys/.search also={/tikz},
}  
\def\mainmacro{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\main@macro}{\main@macro[]}}
\def\main@macro[#1](#2)#3{%
\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{mykeys/.cd,
           d = 1,
           a = 45}
  \pgfqkeys{/mykeys}{#1}
  \path (#2) --+(\macro@a:\macro@d) node[/mykeys/.cd,#1] {#3};
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --( 1,1) coordinate (a) ;
        \mainmacro[a=0,d=12pt,draw,red,shape=circle](a){label 1}    
        \mainmacro[d=2cm,draw,circle](a){label 2}       
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Second solution

You may use the `/.forward to` handler (see p.890 of pgfmanual, v3.0.1a):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /mykeys/.cd,
  d/.code                     = {\def\macro@d{#1}},   
  a/.code                     = {\def\macro@a{#1}},
  /mykeys/.unknown/.forward to=/tikz/\pgfkeyscurrentname,
}  
\def\mainmacro{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\main@macro}{\main@macro[]}}
\def\main@macro[#1](#2)#3{%
\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{mykeys/.cd,
           d = 1,
           a = 45}
  \pgfqkeys{/mykeys}{#1}
  \path (#2) --+(\macro@a:\macro@d) node[/mykeys/.cd,#1] {#3};
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) --( 1,1) coordinate (a) ;
        \mainmacro[a=0,d=12pt,draw,red,shape=circle](a){label 1}    
        \mainmacro[d=2cm,draw,circle](a){label 2}       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but I update my question. Nothing works with the new code.

Comment: @AlainMatthes `/.search also` works with your new example...

Comment: Yes great but do you have an explanation because now I'm lost ...

Comment: The `.search also` handler more or less wraps/redirects/aliases the `.unknown/.code` handler. Paul's code is effectively the same at Percusse's. More strictly I think `.search also` will intercept arguments passed to a key first, if it is specified. if it doesn't catch the arguments pgf will degrade to `.unkown/.code`, if that exists (is specified), else pgf will error out. I'm not sure how `.search also` differs from `.forward to`.