# What is the fundamental difference between .store in and .code in pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf

If someone had a good example to explain the nuances between the two handlers, it would be nice!

Comment: Alain, could you add some more detail to your question explaining why you think these two handlers are so similar? In my understanding, you use `mykey/.store in=\mymacro` in order to be able to access the key value by calling `\mymacro`. The `.code` handler doesn't allow you to do that. Maybe you could include an example of how you're using these handlers?

Comment: An example is here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299272/problem-between-pgfkeys-tikz-and-personal-macro Percusse wrote "I think /.store in handler is better here" and I would like to know why ?

Comment: `path/key/.code={something}` defines, internally, a macro with one argument. It is just like `\def\PathKeyCode#1{something}`. But `.store`, on the other hand, is argument-free.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: Ah, I see. So basically the question is: "Are `d/.code                     = {\def\macro@d{#1}}` and `d/.store in={\macro@d}` equivalent, or is one preferable to the other?". Correct?

Comment: @Jake Yes it's my problem

Comment: Off-topic: It is interesting because the manual more-or-less dismisses `.store in` as superfluous, saying that you might just as well store the value in the key. But I seem to end up using this all the time. Probably because I don't really understand things properly. (But why is it provided if it is really so unnecessary? Is it bad to use it? I'm really unclear.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.store in` handler is defined (line 818 of `pgfkeys.code.tex`) as:

```
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.store in/.code=%
     \pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\def#1{##1}}}
```

So, as Jake says in its comment, the two lines below are equivalent:

```
d/.store in=\macro@d,
d/.code = {\def\macro@d{#1}}
```

The `.store in` handler is just a convenience handler defined by the more powerful `.code` handler.

Comment: so why two handlers to do the same things ? My english is not good enough to understand this kind of subtlety in the pgfmanual ! I love to read the code of pgf but  ...

Comment: @AlainMatthes as I see it the `.code` handler is more general as it allows for arbitrary code while `.store in` always puts its input in a macro.

Comment: (the definition of `.store in` actually is a good example as it is defined in terms of `.code`.)

Comment: @clemens yes it's possible and we can add some extra codes

Comment: @Jake I agree with you when the code looks like what I wrote

Comment: Paul, finally your lines are equivalent but not `.store` in and `.code`. The first one is a special case of the second . `.code`  can be more complex if I understand well all the comments.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I never says that `.store in` handler and `.code` handler are equivalent. As Jake says: `.store in` is just  a convenience handler defined by the more powerful `.code` handler.

Comment: Note that in the def version you have to double as many as possible if `/.code` goes into nested styles etc. `####1` and so on. Also it is already scoped with the current context.

Comment: @percusse You are right... but your remark is valid for any `\def`inition.

Comment: You don't need that if you use `/.store in`

Comment: @percusse Exact (And I understand better Symbol 1's comment: `.store in`  is  _argument free_)