# How does TikZ extract the pgf-keys in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In any TikZ command, for example `\draw`, how does TikZ extract the keys, as they can be in any order.

For example, the following `\draw` statements, give the same output (in different locations in the 2D space though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[->,red,thick,dashed] (0,0) |- (2,2);
\tikz \draw[->,thick,red,dashed] (3,0) |- (0,5);
\end{document}
```

The first `\draw` command has the keys, `red`, `thick` and `dashed`.

The second`\draw` command has the keys, `thick`, `red` and `dashed`.

How does TikZ/LaTeX know, `red` means color, `thick` is thickness of the line.

What is the logic behind this.

Comment: `thick` is a known key, and tikz tries to map unknown keys like `red` to colors.

Comment: Please have a look at p. 962 of the pgfmanual where `.search also` is explained. (The colors do not work *precisely* that way but it explains a bit how it can happen that Ti*k*Z tries to find a reasonable interpretation of a key. The color behavior is determined by `\tikzoption{color}{...}` in `tikz.code.tex`.)

Answer (score 2):

The `pgfkeys` package allows 'styles' to be defined as shortcuts to normal keyvals. Thus `thick` is a shortcut for `line width = 0.8pt` and `red` is (approximately) a shortcut for `draw = red`. Ultimately, which are defined is down to the `pgf` implementers.

---

As mentioned in [Problem between pgfkeys, tikz and personal macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299272/problem-between-pgfkeys-tikz-and-personal-macro), some of these shortcuts are not actually normal keys but are rather found on a specifically-coded path of the `pgfkeys` parser. In particular, many TikZ commands attempt to treat unknown keys as colours before 'giving up'.

Comment: Maybe `thickness = 0.8pt` -> `line width=0.8pt`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the color, shape names and arrow names are not actual keys possible because there are too numerous of them. Here @percusse explains how it is handled in the code.

[Problem between pgfkeys, tikz and personal macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299272)