# Redefining \tikzset inside a TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-matrix

I was playing around with the results from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290490/make-a-pgfkeys-path-take-precedence-over-another-path-for-a-whole-scope) and I found a behaviour I don't fully understand.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\let\oldset\tikzset
\def\fooset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}

\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.search also=/tikz,
  /foo/bar/.style=/tikz/red
}

\let\tikzset\fooset

\tikzpicture

\matrix [matrix of math nodes][bar] {
 p & o & f \\
 l & o & g \\
};

\endtikzpicture

\bye
```

**My intention here is redefining `\tikzset` so that keys in `/foo` are given absolute precedence exclusively in the options of `\matrix` and *nothing else* changes**.

The key `bar` is found as expected (the matrix is red) **but all the code styling cells and nodes seems to be lost**, namely the math mode and the baseline alignment.

My question is: **how do I obtain the behaviour I wanted?**

---

*An explanation of what I tried follows.*

Here's the relevant code from [tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex):

```
\tikzstyle{matrix of nodes}=[%
   matrix,%
   cells={anchor=base},%
   nodes={%
     execute at begin node=,%
     execute at end node=,
     name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn%
   },
   execute at begin cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell,%
   execute at end cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@end@cell,%
   execute at empty cell=\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell
]
```

I tried searching that library, [pgfmodulematrix.code.tex](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex) and [tikz.code.tex](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex) for clues but being still unsure about where the breaking point is precisely I tried to restore the original meaning of `\tikzset` before any damage is done - with a bit of guesswork.

This is what I came up with:

```
\input tikz
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\let\oldset\tikzset
\def\fooset{\pgfqkeys{/foo}}

\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.search also=/tikz,
  /foo/bar/.style=/tikz/red,
  /tikz/hard probe/.code={\let\tikzset\oldset},
  /tikz/soft probe/.style={every matrix/.append code={\let\tikzset\oldset}}
}

\let\tikzset\fooset

\tikzpicture

\matrix
  [every matrix/.append code={\let\tikzset\oldset}]
  [matrix of math nodes][bar]
{
 p & o & f \\
 l & o & g \\
};

\endtikzpicture

\bye
```

gives exactly the expected result: `bar` is recognized and all the styles from `matrix of math nodes` are effective. Also, one can verify that now the `bar` key is no more recognized inside `every cell`, `every node` or any specific node (desired behaviour).

However all of the following make the `bar` key unrecognized:

1. attaching the `[every matrix...]` to any outer scope;
2. using either `[soft probe]` or `[hard probe]` instead of `[every matrix...]` on the `\matrix`.

Also I doubt `every matrix` was ever meant to be used like this, so I'm probably just abusing some loophole (I dont' fully understand) in the expansion order.

Comment: This really feels like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm fiddling around and trying to obtain the behaviour I described above just for the sake of it. I thought that would have been easy but I was surprised by the results. Actually, even an explanation of what's going on with the `every matrix` experiment I did would be great! If you mean XY as in `xy-pics`, my use of `matrix of math nodes` is merely an example.

Comment: Note that if the `.search also` did what you expect here, you should be able to use `red` rather than `/tikz/red`.

Comment: No. I meant XY as in `XY Problem`. This is where somebody asks 'how do I do X?' rather than 'how do I do Y?' because they believe X is the only/best way to do Y, but X is actually impossible/difficult/dangerous, whereas Y is easy/safe to do in another way.

Comment: @cfr The `.search also` does what I expect; I went with `/tikz/red` for clarity (?), `red` has exactly the same effect. Oh, I get the XY thing now - thanks for the clarification! Well, I think I can rephrase the problem hinting at a concrete application like "I need to style matrices locally using keys from `/foo/very/long/path/bar` with precedence over keys in /tikz and without using their full path for brevity". It's kind of a stretch, though.

Comment: If you are just investigating out of interest, I'd recommend starting with something simpler than `matrix of nodes`. Are you really surprised this doesn't work? Most of the library code and interface code does not use `\tikzset`. That's really a user-interface command as far as I can tell. And, as I say, `bar` doesn't work correctly here either. Try testing with something simpler for `bar`, too, such as `draw` rather than `red`. (`red` needs to be handled as it is not itself an option.)

Comment: You're right about the search. Sorry. I must have changed something.

Comment: All you need to achieve that is a single key which changes path and sets the options. Then you don't need to give the full path of the keys. I use this a lot.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code out. I chose `matrix of nodes` because I'm relatively familiar with its short-ish sourcecode (and also to keep the question shorter). Good point, you mean using `.cd`, right? Still, it's not quite what I was trying to achieve. I have to clarify: I'm not surprised because it doesn't work: I'm surprised by the fact that the second code example actualy *does* work and I can't quite pinpoint the reason. Maybe I should rephrase the question to emphasize that, with a more elementary example?

Comment: Yes. `foo/.code={\tikzset{/path/.cd, #1}}` or whatever so you can say `foo={size=10mm,draw=red}` and set `/path/size=10mm` but `/tikz/draw=red` if there is no `/path/draw` and `.search also` is in place.

Comment: why don't you simply put `/foo/.cd` before your options ?

Comment: @percusse Scoping: `*/.cd` affects only the remainder of the current key list. I tried redefining `\tikzset` because I wanted the effect to apply to all keylists passed to `\matrix` (but not to inner nodes).

Comment: `every matrix` gets read too late after `every node` and other things have been tried. And if you modify that then inner nodes will pick them up too. You can simply redefine something `\foomatrix` and you'll have no problems for such hacks. I'm still trying to understand why would you intercept regular TikZ options. As I mentioned in the answer in the linked question, this can only limit available TikZ machinery for the power users.

Comment: @percusse Still, `every matrix` is doing what I wanted when I use it improperly as a key for `\matrix` and I'm not really sure why. However this all feels very brittle so I'll probably just abandon the idea. I'm more interested in calling keys from `/foo` without scope than intercepting/overwriting keys from `/tikz`. Also, why would a power user be limited by that? Worst case, everything is still accessible through the full path, right? (Short of badly messing with `/tikz/.unknown`) Am I missing something?